# How to get cloudwatch metrics of a lambda using boto3 and lambda python & How to draw graph based on data?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

This is Manjusha.

I am working on python + boto3 to get lambda function graphs.

I have seen one example & followed.
from datetime import datetime

```
    targetGroupARN='arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:526788695450:function:dce20-sv-dev-getReservationFunctionV3'
    tgarray=targetGroupARN.split(':')
    target=tgarray[-1]
    response = cloudwatch_client.get_metric_data(
    MetricDataQueries=[
        {
            'Id': 'myrequest',
            'MetricStat': {
                'Metric': {
                    'Namespace': 'AWS/Lambda',
                    'MetricName': 'Invocations',
                    'Dimensions': [
                        {
                            'Name': 'lambda',
                            'Value': target
                        },
                    ]
                },
                'Period': 604800,
                'Stat': 'Sum',
            }
        },
    ],
    StartTime=datetime(2023, 11, 1),
    EndTime=datetime(2023, 11, 6),
    )
```

I am getting following response.
**Output:**
{'Messages': [],
'MetricDataResults': [{'Id': 'myrequest',
'Label': 'Invocations',
'StatusCode': 'Complete',
'Timestamps': [],
'Values': []}],
'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPHeaders': {'content-length': '501',
'content-type': 'text/xml',
'date': 'Mon, 06 Nov 2023 12:04:10 GMT',
'x-amzn-requestid': '4ba7869e-4631-40ca-8ab8-244640b090c5'},
'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
'RequestId': '4ba7869e-4631-40ca-8ab8-244640b090c5',
'RetryAttempts': 0}}

Can some one pls help how to draw graph in python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

To get CloudWatch metrics for an AWS Lambda function using `boto3` in Python and create a graph based on the data, you can follow these steps:

1. **Install** `boto3`: If you haven't already, you need to install the `boto3` library, which is the AWS SDK for Python:

   pip install boto3
2. **Configure AWS Credentials:**

Make sure you have configured your AWS credentials properly. You can use the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI) or set environment variables to configure your credentials. Here's how you can do it using the CLI:

```
aws configure
```

3. **Retrieve CloudWatch Metrics:**

You can use `boto3` to retrieve CloudWatch metrics for your Lambda function. Here's an example of how to do it:

```
    import boto3
    
    # Create a CloudWatch client
    cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    
    # Define the Lambda function name and metric name
    function_name = 'YourLambdaFunctionName'
    metric_name = 'Invocations'  # You can change this to the desired metric
    
    # Get CloudWatch metric data
    response = cloudwatch.get_metric_data(
        MetricDataQueries=[
            {
                'Id': 'm1',
                'MetricStat': {
                    'Metric': {
                        'Namespace': 'AWS/Lambda',
                        'MetricName': metric_name,
                        'Dimensions': [
                            {
                                'Name': 'FunctionName',
                                'Value': function_name
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                    'Period': 300,  # You can adjust the period as needed
                    'Stat': 'Sum',  # You can choose a different statistic (e.g., Average, Maximum, Minimum)
                },
                'ReturnData': True,
            },
        ],
        StartTime='2023-01-01T00:00:00Z',  # Adjust the start time
        EndTime='2023-01-02T00:00:00Z',    # Adjust the end time
    )
    
    # Extract the metric data
    data = response['MetricDataResults'][0]['Values']
    timestamps = response['MetricDataResults'][0]['Timestamps']
    
    # You now have the data and timestamps for your metric
```

4. **Draw a Graph:**

To draw a graph based on the retrieved data, you can use Python libraries like `matplotlib`. Here's an example of how to create a simple line graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Assuming you have 'data' and 'timestamps' from the previous step

# Create a simple line graph
plt.plot(timestamps, data)
plt.xlabel('Timestamp')
plt.ylabel(metric_name)
plt.title(f'{metric_name} for {function_name}')
plt.grid(True)

# Display the graph or save it to a file
plt.show()
```

Make sure to adjust the formatting and style of the graph to meet your specific requirements. You can also explore more advanced graphing libraries like seaborn or `Plotly` for interactive visualizations.

Remember to adapt the code to your specific use case, including the metric name, time range, and graph style.

Comment: HI @Ketan Patel , Thanks For the good Explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the get_metric_data action, there is also a [get_metric_widget_image](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch/client/get_metric_widget_image.html) action which will return to you a graph like what would be used on a CloudWatch dashboard.

[Some languages have an example in the AWS example code library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cloudwatch_example_cloudwatch_GetStartedMetricsDashboardsAlarms_section.html), but it looks like Python SDK does not have one yet.